# point of discontinutinuity $f(x)= x\lfloor \frac {1}{x} \rfloor$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

I have a problem with this exercise, we made at school

Find out, what kind of points of discontinuity does this function have
$f(x)= x\lfloor \frac {1}{x} \rfloor$

at school, we assumed, that $x>0$

Firstly, when I looked at it at home, i suppose, that one point of discontinuity is $0$, because does not belong to a definition scope. 
But I don`t know, if I can define it to make the function continuous, because according to my computations

$\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\lfloor \frac {1}{x} \rfloor = 0*\infty$ and this is indeterminate expression

$\lim_{x\to 0^-}x\lfloor \frac {1}{x} \rfloor = 0*-\infty$ which is also intdeterminate expression..

Are my computations right?

Secondly, at school, we somehow knew, that the point of discontinuity is $\frac{1} {n}$ but why?

then, we wanted to decide what kind of point of discontinuity it is, we solved one-sided limits

but I do not understand the results we get

$\lim_{x\to \frac{1}{n}^-}x\lfloor \frac {1}{x} \rfloor = 1$

but I think that it should be $\frac{n-1}{n}$ becuse I go from the left side, so I never reach that  $\lfloor n \rfloor$ and I have to write $n-1$

and vice versa with the second limit ($\lim_{x\to \frac{1}{n}^+}$) at school the result was $\frac{n-1}{n}$ but I think it should be $1$, because I go from the right side, I get values a bit bigger then $n$, so $\lfloor n \rfloor$ should be n.

Where do I make mistakes ?
And please, try to explain it in a simple way :)
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Limits are made to resolve indeterminate expressions, and their value is either a finite number or it does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nonzero $x$,
$$\left\lfloor\frac1x\right\rfloor\le\frac1x<\left\lfloor\frac1x\right\rfloor+1$$ so that for positive $x$, inverting and multiplying by $\left\lfloor\dfrac1x\right\rfloor$,

$$1=\frac{\left\lfloor\dfrac1x\right\rfloor}{\left\lfloor\dfrac1x\right\rfloor}\ge x\left\lfloor\dfrac1x\right\rfloor>\frac{\left\lfloor\dfrac1x\right\rfloor}{\left\lfloor\dfrac1x\right\rfloor+1}=1-\frac1{\left\lfloor\dfrac1x\right\rfloor+1}.$$

Then by squeezing, the limit is $1$.

For negative $x$, the inequalities must be reversed, but the squeezing remains.

Hence

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=1.$$

Comment: thanks, please, how did you make up the very right equation in the inequation in the middle ? and I do understand, that the function is squeezed from above by 1, but how do you see, that it is also squeezed from bottom ? (and maybye, when I understand this, I also understand the very last equation)

Comment: @martina: typo fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be a positive integer and $x$ be very close to $1/n$.

- If $x>1/n$ then $1/x<n$ and $\lfloor1/x\rfloor=n-1$
- If $x\le1/n$ then $1/x\ge n$ and $\lfloor1/x\rfloor=n$
  This means that
  $$
  \lim_{x\to1/n^-}x\,\lfloor1/x\rfloor=1,\quad\lim_{x\to1/n^`}x\,\lfloor1/x\rfloor=\frac{n-1}{n}.
  $$
  We see that $1/n$ is a point of discontinuity.

For $x\to0$, see Yves Daout's answer.

Comment: thanks,  as I see your explanation, the first bullet point is connected with one-sided limit from the right (I assume that, because $x>1/n$) and therefore I do not understand, how did you come up with the limits below.

Comment: $x$ approaches $1/n$ and $\lfloor1/x\rfloor$ $n$ in one case and $(n-1)/n$ in the other. So $x\,\lfloor1/x\rfloor=1$ on the left and $x\,\lfloor1/x\rfloor=(n-1)/n$ on the right.

Answer (score 0):

> limx→0+x⌊1/x⌋=0∗∞limx→0+x⌊1/x⌋=0∗∞  and this is indeterminate
>   expression
>
> limx→0−x⌊1x⌋=0∗−∞limx→0−x⌊1/x⌋=0∗−∞ which is also intdeterminate
>   expression..

Although the first sentence is true, the second one isn't as when x tends to zero- , the function still tends to positive infinity.
The ponts of discontinuities occur wherever 1/x is an integer as LHL is not exual to RHL like,
 let x tend to 1/2 , then as LHL tends to 1/2 its value is like 1/1.999 and the RHL will be something like 1/2.00001 so your step function in the first case will be 1 and in the second case will be 2.

Comment: Thanks, but why the second function still tends to positive infinity? And what does LHL and RHL mean?

Comment: the second function tends to positive infinity because x tends to zero- and [1/x] tends to negative infinity and two negatives make a positive. 
LHL and RHL are abbreviations for the left hand limit and right hand limit ,i.e , the limit of the function when it is approached on the number line from its left side and from its right